# C++ Access memory violation

Tags: c++

I have an access memory error when i try to instantiate:

```
Ferma(long _id, int _supr, int _nrp, Produs *_produse) :idFerma(_id),suprafata(_supr),nrproduse(_nrp){
    for (int i = 0; i < this->nrproduse; i++)
        produse[i] = _produse[i];
    nrFerme++;
}
```

This is the constructor of the class;visual studio directs me to sec line of the overloaded operator= as a cause of the error;

```
Produs &operator=(const Produs p){
    this->pret = p.pret;
    this->stoc = p.stoc;
    this->denumire = new char[strlen(p.denumire) + 1];
    strcpy(this->denumire, p.denumire);
    return *this;
}
```

and this is the overloaded operator =

```
Ferma f3(55, 1500, nr, prod);
```

i have read prod array from a file and it seems ok;Btw i know i shouldn't use char * but this is the way i have to do it..so any help would be appreciated

Comment: nr also initiated earlier ..

Comment: Regarding that copy-assignment operator, what if `this->denumire` already have been allocated? Then you have a memory leak. And why are you using pointer for strings, when you have [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: thanks for attention ..i know i can use std::string and i also prefer to do so; but in this case i have to use pointers;

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it becomes possible for anyone to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment operator makes a *copy*

```
Produs &operator=(const Produs p){
```

Of the source instance, so is your copy constructor implemented properly?

Comment: problem solved! forgot to allocate memory for the vector of pointers; ty anyway